# mySQL Table Update Concurrency Performance

Tags: java, mysql, performance, concurrency

We have a requirement for a high concurrency table 100+ requests per second.

It is a table that contains a bunch of unique key-codes, these are assigned a request_guid as they are requested.

The table contains an integer primary key, a unique keycode and a null request_guid.

We are running the below query, it works ok with 10,000 records however with 1million+ records it grinds to a halt and each update takes 16+ seconds.

Table:

```
(id INT 
keycode VARCHAR(50) 
request_guid VARCHAR(45) NULL)
```

*Concurrant Query:

```
UPDATE coupon 
SET request_guid = ? 
WHERE request_guid IS NULL 
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;*
```

The RAND() order is being used otherwise we get locking issues when the same row is trying to be updated simultaneously.

Can anyone think of a better way of doing this to improve performance? Potentially the keys should be in a separate table?

I hope the above makes sense, thanks for your help!

Cheers,

F

Comment: you do not need to perform ordering while updating a table, basically you are trying to update all NULL request_guid to a specific value. you can remove 'ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1'.

Comment: This suggests to me that you don't have indexes.  Run EXPLAIN PLAN on your query and look for TABLE SCAN.  If you see one, you know you're missing an index.  That won't scan as your tables add rows.  Why don't you add the request guid when you insert the row?  I don't understand the requirement for the update.

Comment: If your code works, and you're looking for more efficient code,  I would consider that more of a code review question.

Comment: Thanks, however, i only want to update a single row with each request, so i need set LIMIT 1 so that only one row is assigned the request_guid.

The RAND() is there so that a random row is updated, preventing the same row being updated twice, we were getting locking errors without these.

Also the table is indexed on id and request_guid.

Thanks,

F

Comment: @duffymo If I'd had to wager a guess, it would be some kind of limited coupon type of deal that just happens to be implemented poorly. The `ORDER BY RAND()` is just the icing on the cake.

Comment: order by rand suggests a table scan to me.  how can that scale?

Comment: @Kayaman what would you do to improve this?

Comment: Well, as pointed out by many already, your `ORDER BY` hack is a horrible idea. I'd remove that and work out the locking problems in a different way. Your basic requirement is to update a single row (for example the first one) that has a null `request_guid`, right?

Comment: @duffymo basically how can I update a single row without the ORDER BY RAND() and LIMIT. Without the locking issue when the same row is updated at the same time. Maybe it requires a new architecture with a key pool table perhaps, however even then how do you ensure the same key isn't assigned twice? Thanks for your help.

Comment: @kayaman yep correct, need to update the first row with a null guid. When i try to do this 10x per second for example i get locking issues as it keeps picking the same row. Order by rand has been removed :) Any other ideas for a solution? Thanks.

Comment: Probably you can get rid if `id` and promote to `PRIMARY KEY(keycode)`.  If so, the table will be smaller and the processing will be faster.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing it wrong!

First, ORDER BY rand() will have to sort the entire table, so it's going to be horrendously slow.

The answer is to cheat. I will suppose the list of unique keycodes is known beforehand while setting up this particular table, and once it is filled, you want to pick keycodes at random. So let's start with a table "all_keycodes".

```
Table all_keycodes
keycode VARCHAR(50)
```

Now, let's create another table:

```
CREATE TABLE keycodes (
id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
keycode VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
UNIQUE(keycode)
)
```

...And we fill it up with the codes in random order, we do this one time only, when setting up the system.

```
INSERT INTO keycodes (keycode) 
SELECT keycode FROM all_keycodes
ORDER BY rand()
```

Now this table contains an int primary key, which we will use to pull out the keycodes in the order of their ids, which has been randomized.

Now all we must do is deliver these keycodes in order, in a fast manner suitable for a concurrent environment. Unfortunately, MySQL doesn't have sequences, but it does have tables!

```
CREATE TABLE used_keycodes( 
id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, 
request_guid VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
UNIQUE(request_guid)
)
```

Now, you may ask, wtf?

Simple. When you want to claim a keycode, you do:

```
INSERT INTO used_keycodes (request_guid) VALUES (your guid)
```

And the insert_id which is returned gives you the keycode in the other table.

This is concurrent, safe, and it will scale nicely. Most important, no matter how many keycodes have been used, finding one which hasn't been used yet always take the same time, it's just an INSERT.

You can set used_keycodes.id to REFERENCE keycodes.id also.

Comment: thanks for taking time to add such an in depth solution. Will give this a go :) a quick question, if we introduce a keybatch_id in the future where there is multiple batches of keys in the keycodes table, i feel this solution will no longer work? I'm sure we can live with that for now, thanks again :)

Comment: Yeah, it's a bit of a hack, since I use an auto_increment as an atomic shared counter... but it's the only atomic shared counter MySQL has. I believe MySQL can do split PK with auto_increment like (key_batch_id,counter) you'll have to check on that. Or else just create more tables... Makes it easier to DROP them when done, also, instead of slow DELETEs.

Comment: A significant improvement in those two tables:  Get rid of `id` and promote the `UNIQUE` key to be `PRIMARY KEY`.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way would be to remove the `ORDER BY` and to avoid locking by setting the isolation level to `READ UNCOMMITTED` (thus allowing dirty reads).

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED ;
UPDATE coupon SET request_guid = ? WHERE request_guid IS NULL LIMIT 1;
COMMIT ;
```

That should make sure that updates don't compete on the same rows as they are allowed to read the non-null, but uncommitted value in the `WHERE` clause.

Note that this isn't a very stylish solution and it only works if your database supports the `READ UNCOMMITTED` isolation level (which MySQL/InnoDB does).

Comment: Thanks @kayaman. This sounds like a simple answer. However, doesn't this mean you could end up with values overwriting each other if updates occur at the same time? :)

Comment: See the 3rd paragraph of my answer.

Comment: Thanks, will give this a go also!

Comment: I suspect this approach is doomed.  As you fill in `request_guid` values, the `UPDATE` will have to scan farther and farther into the table to find a `NULL`, thereby getting slower and slower.